# How to replace 3 same characters with one in Hive sql?

Tags: sql, regex, hive, grouping

I'm trying to replace 3 same characters with one i Hive sql.
I tried such regex:

`regexp_replace(first_name,"[(\w)\1\1+]", "\1")` and in the result nothing changed.

`Aaabbb-->Aaabbb`

I want to have `Aaab`

I also tried 
`regexp_replace(first_name,"[(\w)\1\1+]", "$1")` and i got error.

When i tried:

`regexp_replace(first_name,"[(\w)\1\1+]", "9")` to check if it works also nothing changed.

Where is the problem?

Comment: Remove the square brackets. Also, I think you need to double the backslashes.

Comment: Please use `Code Formatting`, it makes a huge difference. Thanks :)

Comment: Try `regexp_replace(first_name, '(\\w)\\1{2,}', '$1')`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew and how to get 3 letters and more replace with one?

Comment: If you mean 3 consecutive letters or more to replace with 1: `(\p{L})\1{2,}` => `$1`, see https://regex101.com/r/c8DZJ1/2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should

- Remove the square brackets
- Double the backslashes
- Use `$1` in the replacement.

Use

```
regexp_replace(first_name, '(\\w)\\1{2,}', '$1')
```

Note that `\1\1+` (Group 1 value and then 1+ Group 1 values) is the same as `\1{2,}` (Group 1 value 2 or more times).